# How to customize subject email using Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an event that triggers a listener as soon as a vehicle is created on the system.

This is my event:

```
class VehicleCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $vehicle;

    public function __construct(Vehicle $vehicle)
    {
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
    }

    public function getVehicle()
    {
        return $this->vehicle;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

This is my listener:

```
class SendSchedulingConfirmationListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public function handle(VehicleCreated $event)
    {
        $vehicle = $event->getVehicle();
        $lead = $vehicle->lead;
        Mail::to($lead->email)
            ->queue(new SchedulingConfirmation($vehicle, $lead));
    }
}
```

I used the artisan command to create the email:

```
php artisan make:mail SchedulingConfirmation --markdown=emails.leads.scheduling.confirmation
```

I'm having trouble customizing the subject of the email currently my class looks like this:

```
class SchedulingConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $vehicle;
    public $lead;

    public function __construct(Vehicle $vehicle, Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject('This is my subject')
            ->markdown('emails.leads.scheduling.confirmation');
    }
}
```

When I fire the email it arrives in mailtrap with the subject of **Scheduling Confirmation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the subject in when you new up the mailable:

```
$subject = 'truly awesome subject line';

Mail::to($lead->email)
        ->queue(new SchedulingConfirmation($vehicle, $lead, $subject));
```

So in your class, just add the `$subject` as a param in the constructor:

```
class SchedulingConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $vehicle;
    public $lead;

    public function __construct(Vehicle $vehicle, Lead $lead, $subject)
    {
        $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
        $this->lead = $lead;
        $this->subject = $subject
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->markdown('emails.leads.scheduling.confirmation');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

set the subject in the constructor of the Mailable

```
    class SchedulingConfirmation extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;

        public $vehicle;
        public $lead;

        public function __construct(Vehicle $vehicle, Lead $lead)
        {
            $this->vehicle = $vehicle;
            $this->subject('This is my subject');
            $this->lead = $lead;
        }

        public function build()
        {
            return $this
                ->markdown('emails.leads.scheduling.confirmation');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!